# Access a column in a database Eloquent Laravel4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I need to be able to access all the data in one of the columns of my table. My initial approach was to do something like this. The column i am trying to access in my database is called 'Tags'

```
//get all posts 
$post = Post::get();

//get all post tags
$post_tags = $post['tags'];
```

but this returns null. I know there will be an extremely simple way to do it, i am just not seeing it!

**EDIT**

The reason i am doing this is i have a tagging system in place when something is posted you can add 3 tags which relate to that post. What i am trying to do in the long run is when a tag is clicked it will filter out all the posts with that set tag.

The way this works is when a tag is clicked the user will be redirect to a url like so

```
//test-site.com/posts/tags/{tag}
```

so ill be using that tag to then query the database for the results. I have managed to confuse myself in a task i thought would be farily simple!

Comment: Do you have any relations set for your tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tags are stored in the same table, the problem may be that you are getting a full result set:

```
Post::get();
```

When you should get only one row:

```
Post::first();
```

So this one might do the trick in this case:

```
$post = Post::first();

$post_tags = $post->tags;
```

If you use `Post::get()` or `Post::all()`, you'll have to iterate trough the result set to get your info:

```
foreach(Post::all() as $post)
{
    echo $post->tags;
}
```

Comment: Not too sure how this works, doesn't that mean i would need a tags table in my database? they are currently stored in the same table as the post itself

Comment: Yeah i understand now after having a look at relations it would probably be best for me to store them in there own table. Thanks for the help and the other way works perfect too!